# How to get C standard on my computer?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

I just began programming in C, but I am totally confused.

I used to write code in Visual Studio 2012, but it's compatible with C89 (or ANSI C?). I have installed CodeBlocks with MinGW compiler. I want to learn how to know what is C standard in my computer which I can program? C89, C90, C99 or even C1X? Or I don't understand what it means. What determines C standard in my computer? Compiler or IDE?

Comment: The compiler is the thing that actually has to follow the standard if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @chris so what actually determines the standart of C language?

Comment: @Andrius Do you means "standard"?

Comment: @Andrius, Lots of people.

Comment: Its a compiler thing buddy..use gcc compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't depend on your computer, but your compiler. After all, the computer (by which I mean the CPU) doesn't deal with C but with machine instructions. It is the compiler that interprets C according to some standard and translates that to CPU-friendly instructions.

The [GNU Compiler Collection](http://gcc.gnu.org/) can deal with a variety of C standards, which you can choose from with the [`-std=` flag](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html).

**Addition**: on some (embedded) systems you only have a limited choice of compilers, which may only support a limited number of standards. So in that way the C standard(s) available you may be limited to your computer.

Answer (score 0):

To add a bit to Kninnug's fine answer to help you understand the differences between the standards:

Wikipedia has many useful links describing the differences between the various C's, and even where to get "final drafts" of the standard, which are free. I find these very useful for writing strictly compliant code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_%28C_standard_revision%29 which points to http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Then if you work in the POSIX (e.g., Linux) world the POSIX extensions to the C standard for the UNIX world are useful as well. A good starting point is

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/

This is where you get things, such as getopt(), that are not found in the C standard. Again I recommend exploring Wikipedia pages on the subject.